# tcpdump show strange packet with incorrect src ip and dst ip

Tags: tcpdump, packet

I have private LAN with > 100 servers, in which, I have 3 server:

- x.x.x.37: run memcache on port 11211 (called s37 for short)
- x.x.x.241: run an application server, which connect to memcache on
  x.x.x.37:11211 (called s241)
- x.x.x.46: test server. (called s46)

When I run tcpdump on s46, port 11211, I get strange packet periodically (every 2 hours) as bellow:

```
tcpdump -i eth0 'port 11211'
```

result:

```
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 96 bytes
10:30:22.334411 IP x.x.x.37.11211 > x.x.x.241.57060: . ack 2839551529 win 12
```

Note that I don't have any application which listens on port 11211 on s46.

**So, what causes this symptom? Is there any problem with Ethernet card/Network config on s37? How can I get rid of this problem?**

Thank you in advanced!

**[update 1]**

In my LAN, I have several servers which run memcached. But this symptom only happen to s37 server.

**[update 2]**
tcpdump with -e option:

```
tcpdump -e -i eth0 'port 11211'
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 96 bytes
12:30:22.410129 00:25:90:02:df:31 (oui Unknown) > 00:50:56:81:18:11 (oui Unknown), ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 60: x.x.x.37.11211 > x.x.x.241.57060: . ack 2839551529 win 12
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is a TCP session, and there is only an `ack`, the session is already established.

The source IP and port are the listening memcached server. The destination is the application server client.

Looks to me like it's a heartbeat from the server to the client.

Comment: I wonder why this packet is routed to s46, instead of directly sent to s241? and will s241 receives this packet or not?

Comment: `tcpdump` enables promisc by default. The destination ether is probably a broadcast. Use `-e` to see the layer 2 addresses.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I updated the result of new tcpdump in my question. What tools/software can I use to investigate more in this situation?